# Getting ESX and guest VMs Performance Data Using VMware .NET SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, vmware, vsphere

I'm using VMware SDK for .NET to get overall data from an ESX host and its guest VMs.

I have connected to VMs and got some data from guest such as:

- Max cpu
- Max memory
- IP

Now I want to get performance data (cpu usage, memory usage, alarms, etc) of ESX server. I searched everywhere in the internet and documentation but I couldn't find any good samples that work.

The only thing I know is to use performance manager!

Can anyone help me implement it in my c# code? This is how I connect to my ESX server:

```
VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl c = new VimClientImpl();
ServiceContent sc = c.Connect("https://<my ip add>/sdk");
UserSession us = c.Login("root", "Mypass");
```

And to get the VMs:

```
    IList<VMware.Vim.EntityViewBase> vms = c.FindEntityViews(
            typeof(VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine), null, null, null);
```

Thank you